# Why My OnSelect Event Not Fired Accordingly

Tags: php

Cannot run my select event without reloading entire page even though in php format.

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>     
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src = "home.js"></script>
        <title>Javascript on Steroids</title>
    </head>
    <body> 


            <select id = "purchaseId"  >
                <option value="1" selected >1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Hello , Cannot run my select event without reloading entire page even though in php format.

```
    $myobject = document.getElementById("purchaseType");

    $myobject.addEventListener("change",function(){
      alert("tt");
    })
```

Comment: your select tag id is diffrent bro ,and remove $ sign from myobject  . use this myobject = document.getElementById("purchaseId");

Comment: document.getElementById("purchaseId").addEventListener("change",function(){
  alert("tt");
}) still same no actions

Comment: "_... even though in php format_" I don't see any PHP in that code

Comment: because I save it as php

Comment: Saving it as php don't makes it php, you are not using php code, I only see html and javascript. Please re-tag your post.

Comment: ok sorry bro, btw how to retag?

Answer (score 0):

Your select id is not equal to the id you're calling in your script. 
Furthermore you can change your code to this:

```
$("#purchaseId").change(function() { 
  alert('tt') 
});
```

Here's a fiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lnroksgz/

Comment: still same..==' not triggered at all...it seems like my code don't read ajax or jquery issit?

Comment: In fiddle can trigger but in my localhost xampp not triggeriing at all..how to get the actual path to trigger ajax file and jquery? or my version oldy out-dated?

Comment: It should work fine, unless there's something weird going on in your home.js. Are you using $(document).ready(function() { }); ? Is the path to the file declared properly?

Comment: yes, all have declare accordingly, or can u use teamviewer to help me check my error..cause I really new in this arean

Answer (score 0):

```
  use this in script
     myobject = document.getElementById("purchaseId");
     myobject.addEventListener("change",function(){
      alert("tt");
     })
```

Comment: still same no trigger my alert ("tt")

Comment: is home.js file path proper provided ? if not just inspect in browser console, is there any error showing?

Comment: @BerlySii Cannot reproduce, this is working code. Make sure to use your browser's DeveloperConsole to check for any errors/scripts not loading

Comment: after I inspect it show many warning but didn't show my js file, but it is impossible rtye? cause I already included in my header html

Comment: bro just give right  proper relative path of style.css and  home.js if you are facing issue , just comment those line for a time and then check.

Comment: give me teamviewer id

Comment: I found the solution d..add the $(document).ready(function(){

// your code }); thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

need to include this before the script only able to trigger

$(document).ready(function(){

// your code 
});